# Packages included in the Arch Linux ARM image

Tags: archlinux

I would like to know which packages are included in the default raspberry pi 2 image from archlinuxarm.org. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why do you need to know this? Can't you just install any other packages you need using apt-get? Here are ALL the packages you can use: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=Default&maintainer=&flagged=

Comment: I think you meant pacman? Yes, but I would like to know which packages do I need if I "reset" my system. Also I want to check out if all of these packages are really essentials because for example "raspberrypi-firmware-examples" sounds like not so important.

Comment: raspberrypi-firmware-examples sounds like a system process for updating firmware. You might not want to delete it, just in case. But if you do reset your system, it should install default packages automatically.

Comment: How do you mean "It schould install automatically"?

Comment: meaning it comes with the OS.

Comment: But are the modified raspberry pi linux kernel and the firmware files included if I install the base group of arch linux arm?

Comment: If you get it from raspberrypi.org...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have installed a fresh system, just run:

```
pacman -Q > ~/default-packages.txt
```

I happen to have grabbed a snapshot from an install I did on Oct 24, 2015, so here is the full list of 129 packages that were the default on a Raspberry Pi2 as of that date:

```
acl 2.2.52-2
attr 2.4.47-1
bash 4.3.042-3
bzip2 1.0.6-5
ca-certificates 20150402-1
ca-certificates-cacert 20140824-2
ca-certificates-mozilla 3.20-1
ca-certificates-utils 20150402-1
coreutils 8.24-1
cracklib 2.9.4-1
cryptsetup 1.6.7-1
curl 7.45.0-1
db 5.3.28-2
dbus 1.10.0-4
device-mapper 2.02.132-1
dhcpcd 6.9.3-1
diffutils 3.3-2
dnssec-anchors 20150403-1
e2fsprogs 1.42.13-1
expat 2.1.0-4
file 5.25-1
filesystem 2015.09-1
findutils 4.4.2-6
gawk 4.1.3-1
gcc-libs 5.2.0-2
gdbm 1.11-1
gettext 0.19.6-1
glib2 2.46.1-1
glibc 2.22-3
gmp 6.0.0-2
gnupg 2.1.9-1
gnutls 3.4.6-1
gpgme 1.6.0-2
grep 2.21-2
groff 1.22.3-4
gzip 1.6-1
haveged 1.9.1-2
hwids 20150717-1
iana-etc 20151016-1
inetutils 1.9.4-2.1
iproute2 4.1.1-1
iptables 1.4.21-3
iputils 20140519.fad11dc-1
jfsutils 1.1.15-4
kbd 2.0.3-1
keyutils 1.5.9-1
kmod 21-2
krb5 1.13.2-1
ldns 1.6.17-3
less 481-2
libaio 0.3.110-1
libarchive 3.1.2-8
libassuan 2.3.0-1
libcap 2.24-2
libdbus 1.10.0-4
libedit 20150325_3.1-2
libffi 3.2.1-1
libgcrypt 1.6.4-1
libgpg-error 1.20-1
libidn 1.32-1
libksba 1.3.3-1
libldap 2.4.42-2
libpipeline 1.4.1-1
libsasl 2.1.26-7
libseccomp 2.2.3-1
libssh2 1.6.0-1
libsystemd 227-1
libtasn1 4.7-1
libtirpc 0.3.2-2
libunistring 0.9.6-1
libusb 1.0.20-1
libutil-linux 2.27-6
licenses 20140629-1
linux-api-headers 4.1.4-1
linux-firmware 20150904.6ebf5d5-1
linux-raspberrypi 4.1.11-1
logrotate 3.9.1-1
lvm2 2.02.132-1
lz4 131-1
lzo 2.09-1
man-db 2.7.4-1
man-pages 4.02-1
mdadm 3.3.4-1
mpfr 3.1.3.p4-1
nano 2.4.2-2
ncurses 6.0-3
net-tools 1.60.20130531git-1
netctl 1.11-1
nettle 3.1.1-1
npth 1.2-1
openresolv 3.7.1-1
openssh 7.1p1-1
openssl 1.0.2.d-1
p11-kit 0.23.1-3
pacman 4.2.1-4
pacman-mirrorlist 20151007-1
pam 1.2.1-1
pambase 20130928-1
pciutils 3.3.1-1
pcre 8.37-4
perl 5.22.0-1
popt 1.16-7
procps-ng 3.3.11-2
psmisc 22.21-3
pth 2.0.7-5.1
raspberrypi-firmware 20151023-1
raspberrypi-firmware-bootloader 20151023-1
raspberrypi-firmware-bootloader-x 20151023-1
raspberrypi-firmware-examples 20151023-1
raspberrypi-firmware-tools 20151023-1
readline 6.3.008-3
reiserfsprogs 3.6.24-1
s-nail 14.8.5-1
sed 4.2.2-3
shadow 4.2.1-3
sysfsutils 2.1.0-9
systemd 227-1
systemd-sysvcompat 227-1
tar 1.28-1
texinfo 5.2-4
thin-provisioning-tools 0.5.3-1
tzdata 2015g-1
usbutils 008-1
util-linux 2.27-6
vi 1:070224-2
which 2.21-1
xfsprogs 4.2.0-1
xz 5.2.2-1
zlib 1.2.8-4
```